# Faulty or incompatible RAM stick

Tags: windows-7, memory, compatibility, dram, memory-speed

So I have an old Win7 64bits computer wich im currently upgrading the amount of RAM memory in it. Ive ordered a first 2GB RAM stick online wich was brand new. The specs of that one stick were the following: DDR2,800Mhz, CL5, DIMM and tested latency of 5-5-5-18,non-ECC,unbuffered. This memory stick worked perfectly fine.

So I ordered another one, wich was used but said to be in perfect condition, and from a different brand(I know mixing brand isnt recommanded, but my old RAM stick were a different brand than the previous one I ordered one and they still works good along together). The specs of that used stick were slightly different(I thought they were the exact same before ordering): DDR2,800mhz, DIMM DRAM,CL6(6-6-6), non-ECC, unbuffered.

When I installed that one 2GB memory stick, immediately after, the computer started to go in serious stability issue. I would get lot of BSOD's and crashes, often would get a BSOD even before reaching my desktop wallpaper. So I did a part (not 100%) of a memtest86 test to test the memory sticks I have(4-including the problematic one).

After an hour of the tests, memtest was showing 21 errors, were first error occuring at like 15mb and last one occuring at 2047mb, so I thought maybe that was all on the "new" used RAM stick I had installed. So I removed that stick and installed back the old one, and then the computer went back to working just fine. So the instability was due to that RAM stick.

Now im just wondering if this used RAM stick was really faulty, or if it was just because it wasnt compatible with my motherboard or with the other memory sticks? Also, before installing the used RAM stick, the BIOS screen had always been saying" OK X MB of memory installed 800Mhz " and when I installed the used RAM stick, it would say "OK X MB of memory installed 667Mhz" even though that used stick says it should run at 800Mhz. I would like to know if its more of a compatibility issue, to know if I can just resell this stick, or if I should just get rid of it. Thank you!

Comment: *or if it was just because it wasnt compatible with my motherboard* Then you should at least describe your motherboard.

Answer (score 1):

The module is most likely damaged or defective and can no longer be used. There is only a very small chance there's some incompatibility between it and the system, and the only way you can be sure is to try it in another computer.

You should not try to resell it; you will be reported by the buyer for selling a faulty product.

RAM typically has a lifetime warranty, but it's non-transferable, meaning you can't utilize it if you aren't the original buyer. I'm not sure whether that's legal, but the terms usually claim that, anyway. If you ordered it from an authorized reseller, contact the manufacturer about the warranty. If you bought it somewhere else, such as Ebay, Your best recourse here is to complain to the seller and/or the marketplace and ask for a return or refund. You may simply have to tolerate the loss, if that doesn't go well.

As for the lower clock speed, either the system didn't correctly read the XMP profile from the module, or it is mislabeled. You should be able to change the frequency and timings in the BIOS/UEFI setup, but that won't fix the errors - it defaulted to very safe timings - so don't bother, with this particular module.